# smarty / putting valuable into the double quotations

Tags: php, html, smarty

I'm creating radio buttons from an array. This array is located at another file, because I'm using smarty.
But I couldn't figure out how to set valuable to the html's double quotes.

```
<p>Where you are at?:
<br />
{foreach $myGreeting as $var}
  <input type = "radio" name = "myGreeting" value=""/>{$var}
{/foreach}
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put it inside the quotes (And you'd better escape it).

```
{foreach $myGreeting as $var}
  <input type = "radio" name = "myGreeting" value="{$var|escape}" />
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I totally misread the question! Anyways this might be interesting anyways if you don`t know the radio names beforehand

If you include the name as array key you can use following code:

```
{foreach key=myKey item=myVar from=$myGreeting}
    <input type="radio" name="{$myKey}" value="{$myVar}"/>
{/foreach}
```